# Why does @Valid cause a reentrant flush?

Tags: java, jpa, openjpa, hibernate-validator

When using a `@Valid` annotation with `@OneToMany` relationship, I get a `org.apache.openjpa.persistence.InvalidStateException: Detected reentrant flush.` exception when trying to update my entity. Without the `@Valid` annotation, the update works fine.

Why is the `@Valid` annotation causing the exception here?

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "code")
public class Code {

    @Valid // <-- THE PROBLEM
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "code", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<File> files;

    // ...
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "file")
public class File {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Min(value = 0)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "code_id")
    private Code code;

    // ...

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return (int) id;
    }
}
```

The exception happens on:

```
entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
```

The full exception:

```
<openjpa-2.2.2-r422266:1468616 fatal user error> org.apache.openjpa.persistence.InvalidStateException: Detected reentrant flush.  Make sure your flush-time instance callback methods or event listeners do not invoke any operations that require the in-progress flush to complete.
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.BrokerImpl.flushSafe(BrokerImpl.java:2078)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.BrokerImpl.flush(BrokerImpl.java:1853)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.StateManagerImpl.assignObjectId(StateManagerImpl.java:596)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.StateManagerImpl.assignField(StateManagerImpl.java:683)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.StateManagerImpl.beforeAccessField(StateManagerImpl.java:1655)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.StateManagerImpl.accessingField(StateManagerImpl.java:1586)
    at entities.File.pcGetid(File.java)
    at entities.File.hashCode(File.java:144)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidationContext$BeanAndPath.hashCode(ValidationContext.java:610)
    at java.util.HashMap.hash(HashMap.java:366)
    at java.util.HashMap.getEntry(HashMap.java:466)
    at java.util.HashMap.get(HashMap.java:421)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidationContext.hasMetaConstraintBeenProcessed(ValidationContext.java:336)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.isValidationRequired(ValidatorImpl.java:1281)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateConstraint(ValidatorImpl.java:475)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateConstraintsForDefaultGroup(ValidatorImpl.java:424)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateConstraintsForCurrentGroup(ValidatorImpl.java:388)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateInContext(ValidatorImpl.java:340)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateCascadedConstraint(ValidatorImpl.java:635)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateCascadedConstraints(ValidatorImpl.java:524)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateInContext(ValidatorImpl.java:349)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validate(ValidatorImpl.java:158)
    at org.apache.openjpa.lib.util.J2DoPrivHelper$61.run(J2DoPrivHelper.java:1254)
    at org.apache.openjpa.lib.util.J2DoPrivHelper$61.run(J2DoPrivHelper.java:1252)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.validation.ValidatorImpl.validate(ValidatorImpl.java:278)
    at org.apache.openjpa.validation.ValidatingLifecycleEventManager.fireEvent(ValidatingLifecycleEventManager.java:123)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.BrokerImpl.fireLifecycleEvent(BrokerImpl.java:810)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.StateManagerImpl.fireLifecycleEvent(StateManagerImpl.java:419)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.StateManagerImpl.preFlush(StateManagerImpl.java:3007)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.PDirtyState.beforeFlush(PDirtyState.java:39)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.StateManagerImpl.beforeFlush(StateManagerImpl.java:1034)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.BrokerImpl.flush(BrokerImpl.java:2122)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.BrokerImpl.flushSafe(BrokerImpl.java:2082)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.BrokerImpl.beforeCompletion(BrokerImpl.java:2000)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.LocalManagedRuntime.commit(LocalManagedRuntime.java:81)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.BrokerImpl.commit(BrokerImpl.java:1524)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.DelegatingBroker.commit(DelegatingBroker.java:933)
    at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.EntityManagerImpl.commit(EntityManagerImpl.java:570)
    at entities.CodePersistenceTest.updateCode(CodePersistenceTest.java:768)
```

I'm using OpenJPA 2.2.2 with Hibernate Validator 5.0.2

Comment: Can you show your implementation of `hashCode()` and your ID generation strategy? Based on your stack trace it looks like you're having IDs generated in the database and the ID is used within `hashCode()` which then causes the flush when HV invokes the `hashCode()` method.

Comment: I added the code. `hashCode()` only exists for `file` entity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're referring to the object id in `File#hashCode()` and are using generation type `IDENTITY` which will obtain id values from an identity column in the database, i.e. an access to the DB is required to obtain ids. Apparently your entities are instrumented in a way which causes a flush to happen for that purpose just when reading the id property.

You could try and change your `hashCode()` implementation in a way that it isn't based on the primary key but on the "business identity" of the entity, e.g. the file name or path.

That said, I think Hibernate Validator shouldn't invoke the `hashCode()` method of entities in this situation, so I've filed [HV-848](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HV-848) to get this changed.

Comment: The fix to HV-848 didn't help. Now I see: `HV000041: Call to TraversableResolver.isReachable() threw an exception.` Removing `@Valid` "fixes" the issue.

Comment: Do you have any stack trace you can share?